# Horizontal menu selectable items with arrows buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a menu where you can select the item clicking on them or moving around using arrow items in the menu. Well. I mark selected items using a selected **class** in the set recovered with this **selector**:

```
 $('.mainSlider li:not(.leftBounce,.rightBounce)'); //All li items inside mainSlider without leftBounce and rightBounce classes
```

Problem was that **leftBounce** and **rightBounce** arrow items are marked too (They don't appear in the previous set so I'm confused about this).

I have the next `<ul>` with the items.

```
<ul>
  <li class="leftBounce"><span class="spanBig"> < </span></li>
  <li><span class="spanBig">A</span><span class="spanMedium">ROW</span><span class="spanMedium">GREENS</span></li>
  <li><span class="spanBig">B</span><span class="spanMedium">ROW</span><span class="spanMedium">LIGHTS</span></li>
  <li><span class="spanBig">C</span><span class="spanMedium">ROW</span><span class="spanMedium">GOLD/BROWN</span></li>
  <li><span class="spanBig">D</span><span class="spanMedium">ROW</span><span class="spanMedium">BLUE</span></li>
  <li><span class="spanBig">E</span><span class="spanMedium">ROW</span><span class="spanMedium">BLACK</span></li>
  <li class="rightBounce"><span class="spanBig"> > </span></li>
</ul>
```

I have the next JS Code:

```
var mainli = $('.mainSlider li:not(.leftBounce,.rightBounce)');
var mainliSelected;
var mainLeftBounce = $('.mainSlider .leftBounce');
var mainRightBounce = $('.mainSlider .rightBounce');

/* Main Right Navigation*/
mainRightBounce.click(function(){
    if(mainliSelected){
        mainliSelected.removeClass('selected');
        next = mainliSelected.next();
        if(next.length > 0){
            mainliSelected = next.addClass('selected');
        }else{
            mainliSelected = mainli.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
    }else{
        mainliSelected = mainli.eq(0).addClass('selected');
    }
});
/* Main Right Navigation*/

/* Main Left Navigation*/
mainLeftBounce.click(function(){
    if(mainliSelected){
        mainliSelected.removeClass('selected');
        next = mainliSelected.prev();
        if(next.length > 0){
            mainliSelected = next.addClass('selected');
        }else{
            mainliSelected = mainli.last().addClass('selected');
        }
    }else{
        mainliSelected = mainli.last().addClass('selected');
    }
});
/* Main Left Navigation*/
```

Here a **fiddle** with the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/zomoxp9L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do only two things and it will work as expected:

In main right navigation function:

```
next = mainliSelected.next().not('.rightBounce');
```

In main left navigation function

```
 next = mainliSelected.prev().not('.leftBounce');
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zomoxp9L/